# Accessing Windows 10 public share from Ubuntu without username or password

Tags: ubuntu, networking, mount, windows, cifs

I have a Windows 10 PC with a public share set up, and want to be able to access files on the share without providing a username and password to connect.

Other Windows PCs can access it using ⁠//ServerName/Public without giving a username or a password – they have full r/w access. Also, many Android devices (Nokia 8, Samsung 8, Samsung Tab A) have no problem gaining r/w access to the share without giving a username or password – using, e.g., ES File Explorer.

I have tried various parameters to `mount` and `mount.cifs` without success. The permutations are endless and there is no guiding philosophy. Has anyone done this successfully?

Note that Ubuntu is the client, not the server.

Comment: I understand you want to achieve something. What exactly. Give and example. Explain the restrictions.

Comment: As the title says,  I want to access a W10 Public share r/w from Ubuntu without entering a username or password. This was to be a 'small' stepping stone towards setting up a development environment... it is turning into a major project!

Comment: Very nice project, you accomplished your goal with `samba`. http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/what-is-samba-server-and-how-to-setup-samba-server-in-ubuntu-linux What are the restrictions/requirement?

Comment: Hello Koorb Notsyor. It seems you're trying to use two different accounts, which is why your edit got pushed into the review queue for approval. I'd recommend [you merge them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ServerName/Public /mnt --verbose -o vers=3.0,domain=ServerName,username=guest,guest,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777
```

Because of the `--verbose` option, it might produce a lot of messages regardless of whether it is successful or not, but if it fails, please copy & paste those messages into your original question to enable further troubleshooting.